# Reaping vs. dusting and how to whitelist an account

Tags: frame-system, existential-deposit

The following test can be used in the test suite of pallet-balances:

```rust
#[test]
fn reap_fails_but_account_gets_dusted() {
    ExtBuilder::default()
        .existential_deposit(2)
        .monied(true)
        .build()
        .execute_with(|| {
            assert_eq!(System::inc_providers(&1), frame_system::IncRefStatus::Existed);
            assert_eq!(System::providers(&1), 2);
            assert_eq!(Balances::free_balance(1), 20);
            assert_ok!(<Balances as Currency<_>>::transfer(&1, &2, 19, AllowDeath));
            assert!(System::account_exists(&1));
            assert_eq!(Balances::free_balance(1), 0);
            assert_eq!(System::providers(&1), 1);
        });
}
```

What we see here is that the account is not reaped in the sense that it still exists, but it does get dusted. This seems to contradict info I got on GitHub, but maybe I'm just reading this wrong (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/227). The [docs](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/account-data-structures/#:%7E:text=The%20providers%20reference%20counter%20prevents,pallets%20(%20consumers%20%3D%3D%200).) also say that reference counters prevent the account from being reaped. So I'm starting to get the impression that reaping and dusting are two completely separate processes.

The questions are:

1. Is the behavior above expected or is this a bug?
2. Are reaping and dusting separate processes?
3. How can I whitelist an account in pallet-balances to prevent it from getting dusted?

**Edit.** I may have misread some of the docs. So apparently we can use consumers to make the transfer error. Doesn't answer any of the questions though.

Comment: Which line in the test are you confused about?

Comment: `assert_eq!(Balances::free_balance(1), 0);` According to the claim on GitHub, this should fail.

Comment: I think he means reaped in stead of dusted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are reaping and dusting separate processes?

Yes, [this made it clear to me](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/12194445b222ec4a31ef247d1bced9ba127d7d52/substrate/frame/support/src/traits/tokens/misc.rs#L45-L55):

- dusting: removing remaining balance (e.g. after a transfer) if it is lower than the ED.
- reaping: removing an `account` from storage.

> How can I whitelist an account in pallet-balances to prevent it from getting dusted?

I don't think that is currently possible. There is no way to prevent this other than setting no ED or having `free_balance + reserved_balance > ED`([ref](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/12194445b222ec4a31ef247d1bced9ba127d7d52/substrate/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L1002)). However, if you call `transfer` with `Preservation::Preserve` in stead of `Preservation::Expendable`, it will fail ([ref](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/12194445b222ec4a31ef247d1bced9ba127d7d52/substrate/frame/support/src/traits/tokens/misc.rs#L118-L119)).

> Is the behavior above expected or is this a bug?

From reading the [README](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/balances/README.md):

> No account should ever have a total balance that is strictly between 0 and the existential deposit (exclusive). If this ever happens, it indicates either a bug in this module or an erroneous raw mutation of storage.

Which in the test case you did, you increased the `providers`. So I think it is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Increasing `providers` is an erroneous raw mutation? Why? Also, the first link you provide seems to suggest that if there is a provider, the account won't get dusted. Is that correct?

Comment: 1. Well why are you increasing it to two? 2. If `Preserve` the balance transfer will fail if the amount gets below the ED.

Comment: I concede that increasing it is unnecessary, but why is it not allowed?

Comment: That would require a deeper look into the pallet and a separate question.